# .save() does not change the value of a field , django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to implement a notification system. When the user clicks onto one of the notification from the drop down box , i will use a AJAX Post request to modify the boolean field to indicate that that particular instance of the Notification has been read before.

here is my code:

This is my HTML template:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right myDropDown">
    {%for noti in notifications%}
    {{noti}}
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="top-text-block" id="{{noti.id}}" onClick="return booleanchanger(this.id);">
        <div class="top-text-heading">{{noti.object_type}}</div>
        <p class = 'text-muted'><small>{{noti.time}}</small>></p>
        <div class="top-text-light">{{noti.message}}</div>
      </a> 
    </li>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
```

This is my ajax call :

```
 function booleanchanger(clicked_id){
    var a = clicked_id
    $.ajax({
    url : "{% url 'read-notification' %}",
    type : "POST",
    data : {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : "{{  csrf_token  }}",
         'pk' : a
    },
    success : function(result) {
    }
});
```

This is my notifications model:

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
target = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
message = models.TextField()
object_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
object_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,default = 'test')
is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my view that handles the ajax request:

```
def ReadNotificationView(request):
if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
    pk = request.POST.get('pk',False)
    obj = Notifications.objects.get(pk=pk)
    obj.if_read = True
    obj.save()
    print(obj.if_read)
    return JsonResponse({'status':'Success', 'is_read': 'changed'})
else:
    return JsonResponse({'status':'Fail', 'is_read':'not changed'})
```

this is the url.py:

```
path('notification/update/' , views.ReadNotificationView , name = 'read-notification')
```

print(obj.if_read) from within my view returns me this:
    True

However , going into the django admin page and checking the status of the is_read field shows that the code does not work . Does anyone have a solution for this ? I will greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Typo. In model you got `is_read` in view `if_read`

Comment: wow thank you that was really silly...